# How can I properly detect LetsGoDigital font text?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am on Windows 10, and I try to extract digits from this image

[image: Input image]

with the `pytesseract` library with language `lets` (cf. https://github.com/adrianlazaro8/Tesseract_sevenSegmentsLetsGoDigital or LetsGoDigital, cf. https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr).

I preprocessed my image (grey, threshold and erosion) to get:

[image: Preprocessed image]

But the output of

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='lets')
```

is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set any specific [page segmentation method](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method). I'd opt for `--psm 6` here:

> Assume a single uniform block of text.

So, even without further pre-processing I get the proper result:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('RcVbM.jpg')

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='lets', config='--psm 6')
print(text.replace('\n', '').replace('\f', ''))
# 004200
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
OpenCV:        4.5.2
pytesseract:   5.0.0-alpha.20201127
----------------------------------------
```