# How to recognize digital clock values with Tesseract?

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have 3 pictures of a digital clock:

[image: Digital clock 1]

[image: Digital clock 2]

[image: Digital clock 3]

Task: To somehow recognize the numbers in these photos using `pytesseract`.

I have already tried in the usual way, but Tesseract was unable to determine anything.

Comment: Please sketch `the usual way`.  How did `Tesseract was unable to determine anything` manifest?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant.  Well, as I understand it, tesseract cannot load the "lets" language, but I don't know where to download it

Comment: There is no mention of `lets` in your question post, none of `cannot load`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Improved the pre-processing to properly detect the two new input examples:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract


def detect_7_segments(image):
    config = '--psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="0123456789 "'
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='lets', config=config)


for img_file in ['q0Y40.png', '9dgOm.png', 'XQAfP.png', 'k7BmR.png']:
    img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))
    img = cv2.threshold(img, 64, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    print(img_file, detect_7_segments(img).replace('\f', '').replace('\n', ''))
    # q0Y40.png 0
    # 9dgOm.png 
    # XQAfP.png 67
    # k7BmR.png 85
```

---

Check the LetsGoDigital font, cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67283423/11089932), and [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67804409/11089932) for further details.

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract


def detect_7_segments(image):
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='lets', config='--psm 6')


for img_file in ['XQAfP.png', 'k7BmR.png']:
    img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    print(img_file, detect_7_segments(img).replace('\f', ''))
    # XQAfP.png 67
    #
    # k7BmR.png 85
    #
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.2
OpenCV:        4.5.2
pytesseract:   5.0.0-alpha.20201127
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: There was such an error: pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file C:\\Users\\Sergey\\AppData\\Local\\Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/lets.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'lets\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')

Comment: You must download the `lets.traineddata` file from the linked repository in the linked Q&A, and put it in the `tessdata` folder, which seems to be `C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata` on your machine.